# php.ini file is available in xamp folder

Tags: php, xampp

I am new to php and started running small codes in php ..

**Operating System- Windows Xp service pack 3
Xampp version - 1.7.3
netbeans- 6.5**

for small codes such as upload etc are working perfectly, But when I try to send email said error message SMTP related .Then, I started surfing Google about errors , there I come to know about php.ini file in xampp. Different versions have different locations of this file in xampp only.

There are 3 things I noticed...

1) xampp folder and subfolders does not have **php.ini file**

2) on Running **phpconfig()** it shows :

**Configuration File (php.ini) Path     no value**

**Loaded Configuration File     C:\xampp\php\php.ini**

3)SMTP server is deactivated in **xampp Status at localhost/xampp**

**SMTP Service   DEACTIVATED

FTP Service  DEACTIVATED**

I can't edit php.ini as its not available what is solution to these problems?

Comment: did you look at xampp/php. There you can see php.ini file

Comment: what happens when you just activate SMTP via xampp admin?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

With XAMPP, the php.ini file is called php
Click on the file called php then you will see another folder called php, click on that, this is the php.ini file

Answer (score 1):

Please have a visit on following page and navigate to configuration files session:

```
http://www.apachefriends.org/en/xampp-windows.html
```

I would recommend you to use WAMP Server. As you are new to PHP WAMP server have less configuration settings and easy to use as compare to XAMPP.

Answer (score 1):

I don't know what is the situation but i would recommend these thing.

- php.ini is under xampp>php folder
- if you downloaded xampp.rar/.zip and unzip in a directory then please run xampp>setup.bat found in xampp folder
  it will be needed whenever you will relocate your xampp folder.
- for sending mail you should ther are two options:-
  first by you own smtp server
  and 
  by some other like gmail,yahoo, microsoft etc.
  In first case setup mail server as come with xampp and add smtp related entry in php.ini
  In second you will only need to add smtp related seeting to php.ini
  basic settings are:

  - smtp host :
  - smtp port :
  - smtp username:
  - smtp password:

so whenever you will send email , email will be sent from this email id.

Answer (score 0):

open the xampp control panel .then click apache module config button .you will get some list.after that click the php.ini file.it will open into editor automatically.

[image]