# curl_init() has been disabled for security reasons

Tags: php, curl

> ```
> $url= "http://api.stackoverflow.com/1.1/search?tagged=php";
> $ch = curl_init();
> curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL,$url);
> curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER,1);
> curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_ENCODING, ""); // this will handle gzip content
> $result = curl_exec($ch);
> curl_close($ch);
> print $result;
> ```

Error

```
Warning: curl_init() has been disabled for security reasons on line 2

Warning: curl_setopt() has been disabled for security reasons on line 3

Warning: curl_setopt() has been disabled for security reasons on line 4

Warning: curl_setopt() has been disabled for security reasons on line 5

Warning: curl_setopt() has been disabled for security reasons on line 6

Warning: curl_exec() has been disabled for security reasons on line 7

Warning: curl_close() has been disabled for security reasons on line 8
```

May i Know the reason why my Curl not working ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you are on xampp look below

[How to enable curl in xampp?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3020049/how-to-enable-curl-in-xampp)

you should only need to change this php

C:\Program Files\xampp\php\php.ini

Comment: No i am checking it on localhost (xampp)

Answer (score 3):

From your php.ini remove those above functions from `disable_functions`.

[How to locate the php.ini file (xampp)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6185319/how-do-i-edit-php-ini-file-in-xampp-server)

[php.ini file is available in xamp folder](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16934487/php-ini-file-is-available-in-xamp-folder)

Answer (score 1):

**Contact your hosting!** :)

Or try:

```
file_get_contents('http://api.stackoverflow.com/1.1/search?tagged=php');
// Most likely it's also blocked.
```

You can also try to download with [`streams`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/wrappers.http.php).

Or use [`sockets`](https://www.php.net/sockets) and connect directly to server and send a HTTP request and parse the response yourself.

*There are ways, don't know if they work on your setup... if cURL is not available.*

Answer (score 0):

Open your `php.ini` file and check for `disable_functions` over there. And see whether your `curl_init` is packed there or not! Here is [More information](http://www.2by2host.com/articles/php-errors-faq/disabled_curl_init/)