# Trying to get API output in PHP

Tags: php, json

I am trying to get output of this API using php. It's a Australia Post Freight calculator. I am not sure what is wrong with it, can some one please suggest. It will be really helpful.

```
// Set your API key: remember to change this to your live API key in production
$apiKey = API_KEY;

// Set the URL for the Domestic Parcel Size service
$urlPrefix = URL_PREFIX;
$parcelTypesURL = 'https://' . $urlPrefix . '/postage/parcel/domestic/size.json';

// Lookup domestic parcel types (different kinds of standard boxes etc)
$ch = curl_init();
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $parcelTypesURL);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, array('AUTH-KEY: ' . $apiKey));
$rawBody = curl_exec($ch);

// Check the response: if the body is empty then an error occurred
if(!$rawBody){
die('Error: "' . curl_error($ch) . '" - Code: ' . curl_errno($ch));
}

// All good, lets parse the response into a JSON object
$parcelTypesJSON = json_decode($rawBody);
```

Comment: If that is your API key, you should hide it. Is this code bringing up any errors?

Comment: That code works. a `print_r($ParcelTypesJSON)` shows the data I would expect. If there is an error, it is outside that code.

Comment: WARNING curl_init() has been disabled for security reasons on line number 9

This is one of the warning, and this key is the testing one that is why did not hide it

Comment: Then your issue is not the code, it is that `curl_init()` has been disabled for security reasons. These warnings are usually there to give you information regarding errors. When asking for help, if you have an error, document the error.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> curl_init() is disabled for security reasons...

This means that the server has disabled that function.
If you have control of the server, then enable `curl_init()` in the `php.ini`.
 [More information here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22075803/curl-init-has-been-disabled-for-security-reasons).
If you do not, try using `file_get_contents()`. [more information here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2445276/how-to-post-data-in-php-using-file-get-contents)

Comment: or - if your host wont give you curl and and you need curl, move hosts